# Fullpage.js - Reset all slides to first Slide upon leaving Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I am using FullPage.js v2.7.4
When a user changes slide and then leaves that section for another one, returning to that section will result in having the last slide they visited appear.

I would like to make it so that when a user is on (lets say) slide 4 in section 2, and they leave to go to section 3, returning to section 2 will show slide 1, instead of 4.

I have tried the other solutions posted on SO but they're not doing anything (guessing its a version issue).

My fullpage_init.js looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
            menu: '#menu',
            scrollingSpeed: 1000,
            onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var section = $('.section').eq((index - 1));
                    if (section.find('.slides').length) {
                        $.fn.fullpage.scrollDefault(section, 0);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My main.js looks like this:

```
$.fn.fullpage.scrollDefault = function(section, slide){
    if(typeof slide != 'undefined'){
        var slides = section.find('.slides');
        var destiny =  slides.find('[data-anchor="'+slide+'"]');
        if(!destiny.length){
            destiny = slides.find('.slide').eq(slide);
        }
        if(destiny.length){
            landscapeScroll(slides, destiny);
        }
    }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The plugin doesn't provide any option to do it. You would have to modify the plugin by yourself or ask for a customization.

Comment: Can I hire you to customize it for me?

Comment: Sure, just [contact me](http://alvarotrigo.com/#contact-page) as said in the docs.

Comment: Just to mention that this is now possible with a fullpage.js extension.